# what does "* Connection #0 to host example.com left intact" mean?

Tags: curl

I'm using curl with `curl -v https://example.com`

and at the end it says `* Connection #0 to host example.com left intact`. What does that mean?

Comment: It says just that it keeps the session alive for 60s by default. [How do I make cURL use keepalive from the CLI?](https://serverfault.com/questions/199434/) or [CURL OOTW: –KEEPALIVE-TIME](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2020/02/10/curl-ootw-keepalive-time/).

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Adding a header "Connection: close" to your CURL command should solve the problem:

```
curl -v -H "Connection: close" https://example.com
```

Explanation can be found in [this article](https://www.sneppets.com/software/connection-0-to-host-localhost-left-intact/):

**Why is the connection left intact ?**

> The connection is left intact, because the server allowed it to stay
> open and CURL no need to close it after you receive the response for
> the request sent. That’s why the requests return ‘Connection:
> keep-alive‘ headers when you expect ‘Connection:close‘
>
> If you wanted to close the connection, then you could send CURL
> request with ‘Connection: close‘ as shown below and you could see ‘*
> Closing connection 0‘ in the response.

I hope the article https://www.sneppets.com/software/connection-0-to-host-localhost-left-intact/ helps you solve your problem.

Comment: So it means it was successful?

Comment: @DavidBrossard Not necessarily. It just means, what was explained above - the socket connection to the HTTP server was left intact. It will close once curl exits anyway. But you could have got a 400 error and still have your connection left intact.

Comment: There is no problem to solve though, and most users have no need to add that header.

Comment: need a switch though - as this is not ideal (or working) for FTP.

Answer (score 27):

Short answer: it doesn't mean anything, when you just request one URL. After `curl` is finished and the process exits, the connection is **not** left intact anywhere despite the misleading message; it is closed just like you'd expect.

The connection is only reused if you fetch multiple URLs in the same `curl` invocation. In that case it's a good thing, and you shouldn't need to force the connection to close, unless you're debugging connection issues.

(I too went looking for answers, when I wanted to check that `curl` doesn't somehow keep the connection open in the background of my shell. It doesn't.)